# Git: duplicate local repo with unpushed commits

Tags: git

I cloned a github repo. I made some modification and commit them locally but I didn't push them to github. I created a new repo in bitbucket and intended to push my local repo to this new repo using:

```
cd my_local_repo
git push --mirror url_new_repo
```

This seemed to work at first, but I see that the commits I made and I didn't push to github haven't been pushed to the url_new_repo in bitbucket. How do I push my local commits to the url_new_repo?

Comment: Why don't you push your local commits to the _old_ repo first, and then carry on with what you were already planning to do?

Comment: I can't do that. It's a thirdparty private repo that I'm not supposed to contribute to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a remote first as follow:

```
$> git remote add bitbucket_origin <your-bitbucket-repo-url>
```

you can now see this added remote by running:

```
$> git remote -v
```

Now, push your local version of the repository to the bitbucket:

```
$> git push bitbucket_origin <your-branch-name>
# <your-branch-name> is where you're checked-out to locally
# It can be seen by:
$> git branch
```

Adding remote: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: I think that what I first tried didn't work because my unpushed commits were in a detached HEAD. I had to rebase the detached HEAD into master before I could apply your solution.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can add a second remote and then push to the second remote

```
$ git remote add bitbucket path/to/your/repo.git
$ git push bitbucket
```